# How to get Ola Cabs Api key?

Tags: android, api

I need to implement Ola cabs Api in an android app. I am following this link - http://docs.console.olacabs.com/ola.

But everytime I try and fetch some data, it says "Authorization Error". I need a valid Api key to use the services but can't find a way or link to generate one.

Comment: I think you should contact them as this information doesn't seem to be provided in their "docs" or anywhere else.

Comment: I have tried contacting them, no reply. Thanks though.

Comment: I think this is a private API, so probably you won't get access to this. What you could probably to is to sniff their official app and see how they do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try @ndo1d
http://blog.attify.com/2015/02/01/ola-cabs-privacy-security-issue-discovered-appwatch/

https://medium.com/@CodeTheDevil/busting-ola-wallet-1ceea6174b1f

You can use the application normally, and AppWatch will show you the real time application’s network traffic. AppWatch is an intelligent platform, with which it automatically identifies APIs which could be vulnerable. As soon the app does something which AppWatch identifies to be vulnerable, it simply displays a vulnerable tag along with the request.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have to insert an API Key in the header of the request to access API's functions.

I don't know exactly if it's the case, or if you have generated the API Key, if this key has authorization to access the resource you want.

Please check: Do you have an API Key? Does it provide access to what resources?

ps: I can't comment. That's why I wrote an answer.

Comment: That is the issue. I don't have an Api key and don't know how to generate one. I have just received word from  official source stating that their Api is private for now and will be released for developers in near future.

Comment: Ok, so nothing to do then. See you.

Answer (score -1):

Register here to get API Key..
https://developers.olacabs.com/docs/ride-availablity